# Сортировка выбранной строки двумерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Пожалуйста, напишите кусок кода, который сортирует выбранную строку двумерного массива. Пишу - не работает, вставляю готовый код - не работает

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int n = 4; // размер массива
    int arr[n][n];
    cout << "Введите массив:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "arr[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]" << ": ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];  // ввод элементов массива
        }
    }

    cout << "=============================================" << endl;

    cout << "Введенный массив:" << endl; // вывод заполненного массива
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    cout << "=============================================" << endl;

    int choice = 0, temp;
    cout << "Выберите строку, которую вы хотите отсортировать, выберите значение от 0 до 4:" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    // сортировка

    cout << "Полученный массив:" << endl; // вывод результата 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

}
```

Comment: Я в вашем коде вижу только 2 раза вывод массива, но никак не сортировку.

Comment: C++? Значит, `sort(&arr[choice][0],&arr[choice][n]);` :)

Answer (score 5):

```
std::sort(arr[choice], arr[choice] + n);
```

Или, если же самому нужно написать, то:

```
int i = 0;
int* first = arr[choice], *last = first + n;
while (first != last) {       
    for (int* p = arr[choice]; p != last- i - 1; ++p)
        if (*p > *(p + 1)) {
            int temp = *p;
            *p = *(p + 1);
            *(p + 1) = temp;
        }
    ++first;
    ++i;
}
```

Это один из самых простых вариантов сортировки.

То же самое без указателей(по просьбе автора):

```
int  i = 0;
while(i < n) {
    for (int j = 0;  j < n - i - 1; ++j)
        if (arr[choice][j] > arr[choice][j + 1]) {
            int temp = arr[choice][j];
            arr[choice][j] = arr[choice][j + 1];
            arr[choice][j + 1] = temp;
        }
    ++i;
}
```

P.S. рекомендую изучать разные альгоритмы сортировки. Для строки  `choice` двумерного массива просто рассматриваются элементы от  `arr[choice][0] и до arr[choice][n]`, где `n`  это количество столбцов.

Comment: А можно ли без указателей? Без указателей код попроще, спасибо)

Comment: Может быть для вас проще, но для меня без разницы. Если у вас есть какие то проблемы связанные неясным пониманием, то советую это быстро устранить изучением. Но допишу для вас и без указателей, чтобы вы могли сравнить и понять то же с указательями

Comment: Допишу позже. Извените, но сейчас нет времени...